# Как привязать цикличный таймер обратного отсчета (jQuery от Keith-Wood) к времени сервера?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, countdown

Уважаемые мастера! 
Цикличный таймер обратного отсчета от http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html 
Надо установить его на больший срок, примерно на 40 часов. 
Однако, при обновлении страницы, таймер обнуляется.  
Привязка к серверу, согласно инструкции, не работает.  
**Как привязать цикличный таймер ко времени на сервере?** 
Текущая разметка, может быть где-то была допущена ошибка?:

```
<div class="countdown">
       <div id="countdown"></div>
       <span class="help-text">Часов до запуска</span>
</div>
```

Скрипт вызова:

```
// Вызов цикличного таймера на 30 секунд, чтобы проще было проверять, привязан таймер к времени сервера или нет
    var liftOff;
    $(function () {
        $('#countdown').countdown({until: +30, format:'s', serverSync: serverTime, onExpiry: liftOff});
    });
    liftOff = function() {
        $('#countdown').countdown('destroy');
        $('#countdown').countdown({until: +30, onExpiry: liftOff});
    };

    // Эта функция берет время из php файла
    function serverTime() {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({url: 'http://test.html/serverTime.php',
            async: false, dataType: 'text',
            success: function(text) {
                time = new Date(text);
            }, error: function(http, message, exc) {
                time = new Date();
            }});
        return time;
    };
```

Скрипт времени:

```
// Это php файл, должен выдавать текущее время сервера таймеру
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: Задача не решаема. Можно не тратить время. Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0):

В `countdown({...})` необходимо добавить [параметр](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#since) `since`, он отвечает за дату начала отсчета. Если это поле не добавлять то по умолчанию оно `null` и отсчет берется от текущего времени. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/weyjqca7/2/)

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте добавить параметр `since`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за участие. Все равно обнуляется. Видимо не судьба запустить калькулятор. Это уникальное решение, нигде не видел отдельных скриптов чтобы с сервером синхронизировались

Comment: Я тоже первый раз вижу плагин с такой возможностью. Добавление параметра не помогло ?

Comment: нет, все также обнуляется.
Простите, что отнял время.

Comment: Сделал пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weyjqca7/2/), время не обнуляется после обновления.

Comment: Таймер идет на увеличение. Если сделать на убывание, то опять после обновления число обнуляется. Спасибо за старание...